# Interleaved execution of while loops in the Dart language using async and await

Tags: async-await, dart, blocking, nonblocking

Please demonstrate in a simple dart code snippet that while loops that perform calculations (e.g. optimization or model fitting) that are under internal control (other than operations controlled from the opaque outer context like file access)  can be run in interleaved way.

My hypothesis is that it is not possible unless one runs a blocking instruction within each while loop like file access or the use web sockets.

The documentation on asynchronous programming in dart does not mention the term "blocking" in that sense. The documentation on asynchronous programming in vertx (java application server library) does. But I dont know if the latter can be generalized since platforms could implement different intentions about asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is. Your hypothesis, if I understand it correctly, is correct.

Dart is single-threaded inside each isolate. Only one thing in each isolate can be executing at a time.

That does mean that a long calculation that never does an asynchronous operation, won't interleave with other calculations.

If the computation does asynchronous operations (which means waiting for something else), then something else does get to run.

Comment: Good to know, perhaps I was confused by my vertx/java experience ... The eventloop might do a different job there. On java there can be more than one thread.

Answer (score 4):

`Isolate` class can run multiple threads in the VM or webworkers in the browser.

Edit: It's not my job to write the code to demonstrate that, or to invoke a google search on "dartlang examples isolates" on your behalf.  My answer answers your question precisely.  You run multiple threads using isolates, and they can do independent long-running calculations that communicate with each other through Ports.

Comment: What conclusions can I draw concerning my question? You say that isolates can, but that does not demonstrate that theres a way to interleave async functions containing time consuming calculations to falsify my hypothesis ... so, it doesnt answer my question.